# EasyMock + PowerMock : How to mock field?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, easymock, powermock

Let's look at this piece of code :

```
    public class A {

        public void doSmth() {  // pay attention - void method
           // impl
        }
    }

    public class B {
       private A a_instance; // null

       public void doSmthElse() {
          a_instance.doSmth(); // NPE here without mock
          // also do smth. else
       }
    }
```

Now, I have `B b = new B();` and I want to test `b.doSmthElse()` , but I need to create a mock for `a_instance` object before, otherwise I will get `NullPointerException` ! How can I achieve this with EasyMock or PowerMock ???

Comment: What have you tried? Are you using a dependency injection library or framework?

Comment: What do you mean ? Yeap, in real life a_instance  object is being injected there, but for unit test I need to mock it.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Test
public void testDoSomething()
    {
    // setup: sut
    B b = new B();
    A mockA = EasyMock.createMock(A.class);
    b.setA_instance(mockA); // If you have a setter

    // setup: expectations
    mockA.doSmth();

    // exercise
    EasyMock.replay(mockA);
    b.doSmthElse();

    // verify
    EasyMock.verify(mockA);
    }

@Test
public void testDoSomething_setUsingReflection()
    {
    // setup: sut
    B b = new B();
    A mockA = EasyMock.createMock(A.class);
    // Set the collaborator using a Spring reflection utility
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(b, "a_instance", mockA);

    // setup: expectations
    mockA.doSmth();

    // exercise
    EasyMock.replay(mockA);
    b.doSmthElse();

    // verify
    EasyMock.verify(mockA);
    }
```

Comment: Then I need to have setter for a_instance which (I mean setter method) I am gonna use only in test purposes. It's not very good practice to have code which is being used only for tests within class which contains some business logic for example.

Comment: That's a different problem and there are many different solutions. You can make the collaborator public, use reflection to set it or use an utility like Spring's [ReflectionTestUtils](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html).

Comment: No, reflection will not work, because I use EasyMock to create mock for B class and that is why if I try to get that field using reflection, I will get NoSuchFieldException because I have no idea how that field is called when the mock is created.

Comment: You don't need to use EasyMock to create the B instance (it's your sut), only to create the A mock.

If you don't have a public setter it does mean you are using a framework to inject the a instance, and that fwk for sure uses reflection. You have then to use also reflection in your test.

I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
instanceName.methodName();
Easymock.expectLastCall(); //for void methods this is how it is done
```

instanceName can be mocked or actualInstance.

If u can make the method static then it is easier with powermock

```
Powermock.mockStatic(ClassNameContainingStaticMethod)
```

All static methods get mocked directly

Word of Caution:- Converting a method to static can have issues in other parts.Do it carefully

Hope it helps.
All the best!

Comment: The `Easymock.expectLastCall();` is not necessary.

Answer (score -2):

I don't see a reason why PowerMock is required here. You can achieve that with EasyMock itself.

```
@Test
public void testDoSmthElse() {
    A a = EasyMock.createMock(A.class);
    EasyMock.expect(a.doSmth()).andReturn(/*some value */);
    EasyMock.replay(a);

    B b = new B();
    Object whatever = b.doSmthElse();

    assert(); // psuedo-line. Add whatever assertion required
}
```

Note: Import appropriate classes

Comment: Replace that line simply with `a.doSmth();` and the test will pass.

Comment: you need to inject object A's into B before calling b.doSmthElse()